# Does Spring webflux support jsp view/tiles view

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflux, apache-tiles, tiles-3

I'm upgrading spring version in our application which was on spring 4.3 earlier, while upgrading to spring 5 we want to change some part of application to use reactive features available. Both MVC and WebFlux is working side by side in application but view resolution is not working in webflux is it not supported.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/react/createWithReactive")
    public Mono<String> reactCreateWithReactive(Model map) {
              return Mono.just("createPage");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per official spring documentation view resolution is same as MVC

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.x/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-viewresolution

> 1.3.6. View Resolution Same in Spring MVC
>
> View resolution enables rendering to a browser with an HTML template
>   and a model without tying you to a specific view technology. In Spring
>   WebFlux, view resolution is supported through a dedicated
>   HandlerResultHandler that uses ViewResolver's to map a String,
>   representing a logical view name, to a View instance. The View is then
>   used to render the response.
>
> Handling Same in Spring MVC
>
> The HandlerResult passed into ViewResolutionResultHandler contains the
>   return value from the handler, and also the model that contains
>   attributes added during request handling. The return value is
>   processed as one of the following:
>
> String, CharSequence — a logical view name to be resolved to a View
>   through the list of configured ViewResolver's.
>
> void — select a default view name based on the request path minus the
>   leading and trailing slash, and resolve it to a View. The same also
>   happens when a view name was not provided, e.g. model attribute was
>   returned, or an async return value, e.g. Mono completed empty.
>
> Rendering — API for view resolution scenarios; explore the options in
>   your IDE with code completion.
>
> Model, Map — extra model attributes to be added to the model for the
>   request.
>
> Any other — any other return value (except for simple types, as
>   determined by BeanUtils#isSimpleProperty) is treated as a model
>   attribute to be added to the model. The attribute name is derived from
>   the Class name, using Conventions, unless a handler method
>   @ModelAttribute annotation is present.
>
> The model can contain asynchronous, reactive types (e.g. from Reactor,
>   RxJava). Prior to rendering, AbstractView resolves such model
>   attributes into concrete values and updates the model. Single-value
>   reactive types are resolved to a single value, or no value (if empty)
>   while multi-value reactive types, e.g. Flux are collected and
>   resolved to List.
>
> To configure view resolution is as simple as adding a
>   ViewResolutionResultHandler bean to your Spring configuration. WebFlux
>   Config provides a dedicated configuration API for view resolution.
>
> See View Technologies for more on the view technologies integrated
>   with Spring WebFlux

Comment: There are two interfaces of view resolver as below for MVC and WebFlux
MVC:
org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver
Has method View resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale locale) throws Exception;

WebFlux: org.springframework.web.reactive.result.view.ViewResolver  Mono<View> resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale locale);

As both interfaces are different and there is no implementation for reactive in tiles as of now.